# Parse CLI not updating project files

Tags: parse-platform

I was working on my Parse app and suddenly I started not being able to update using the Parse CLI on OS X. I was saving the files as always, but it started not updating. I've updated the CLI, and now I'm getting a constant loop:

```
Note that the following files will not be uploaded:
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/iOS/uLouder/uLouder/public/.DS_Store
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/iOS/uLouder/uLouder/public/img/ulouder/.DS_Store
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/iOS/uLouder/uLouder/public/js/rs-plugin/.DS_Store
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/iOS/uLouder/uLouder/public/js/rs-plugin/css/.DS_Store
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/iOS/uLouder/uLouder/public/js/rs-plugin/js/.DS_Store
/Users/Can/Documents/Programming/iOS/uLouder/uLouder/public/presentation/.DS_Store
```

I'm constantly getting this error in a loop every few seconds, and my files aren't updating on the server. How can I get rid of this problem? I need to update some files immediately.

UPDATE: I've removed the `.DS_Store` files, that error is gone, but still, my files aren't updating when I save them as usual.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I'm having the same problem. Still looking for a work around.

Comment: @worstoo could you please post it if you find a solution, I'm having really hard time too.

Comment: I removed the .DS_Store files and waited. Things seemed to resolve themselves. The [parse status page](https://status.parse.com/) showed an error earlier in the day. May have been related.

Comment: @worstoo I've removed them too, the error message involving them went away, but still, my files are not updating, successfully. Some files DO update, but not my main.js, which is critical as I'm trying to add some cloud functions.

Comment: @worstoo it appears to be related to something in a 'require'd file, apparently recursive. I'm trying to track down to the exact line that causes the error. I wish Parse told where the error exactly was.

Comment: same here :( I've sent a report in the Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/Jvr5szGK6g0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a syntax error in one (or more) of the files. Instead of `parse develop ProjectName`, use `parse deploy` to commit, and it will tell the correct file name and line number of the error instead of doing nothing as in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

On a unix environment, files and folders that start with a `.` ([dotfiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)) are considered hidden. It sounds like the tool is ignoring these files by design.

Comment: Hi Hector, I think this particular issue is a symptom of another bug. I'm again seeing strange looping behavior in the cli. I'm continuously seeing the last line of the log file printed to the screen. This is similar to the bug I saw yesterday where the diagnostic message was being repeatedly displayed. The diagnostic message is likely not an issue, however the repeated display of it is.

Comment: @worstoo Looping in the cli is an unrelated bug, please upvote the bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1604202406501554/